# .htaccess redirect to subdirectory on Verio windows server

Tags: .htaccess, iis, windows-server-2003, isapi-rewrite

I've been trying to get a website up an running on my work's servers using Verio windows server 2003 gold and they've been quite useless when it comes to helping me out.

All I'm trying to do is set up a Wordpress installation, which they apparently require to be in a subdirectory. This is done and I have it in domain.com/wp ready to go. At this point they recommend that I use an .htaccess file to redirect to that url, so as they just sent me basically an "About .htaccess" link, that was of no help.

Did some searching, found a couple options like this one:
http://www.site5.com/blog/apache/htaccess/redirect-to-blog/20090427/
and nothing I use seems to work, not even as a straight redirect. Just gives me a  "Directory Listing Denied - This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed."

I do want to mention I did enable URL Rewrite for IIS via ISAPI_Rewrite 3 in the control panel.

As I mentioned Verio support is useless and I can't seem to find anything searching that seems to help my situation.

So pretty much what I need is domain.com/wp to rewrite as domain.com so all links centered around it do the same (ie domain.com/about domain.com/contact)

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correct you need your Wordpress application to be available from the root of your web site instead of /wp/ folder? Then please try following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(?!wp/)(.*) /wp/$1 [NC]
```

By the way I think you could try simply copying /wp/ folder content to the root folder.